# Как передать state в виде props?

Tags: reactjs

Есть два файла App и App2. Как передать state из одного файла в другой в качестве props b вывести его на страницу?

Answer (score 0):

Я так полагаю, что у вас такая ситуация, когда компоненты не вложенные один в другой, а так сказать лежать на одном уровне.

Эту задачу можна решить несколькими путями:

1. Вам нужно стейт создавать в общем компоненте (скажем AppMain)
   В компонент App передавать props с колбек функцией, которая позволит сменить стейт 
   А в компонент App2 передавать props со значением
2. Использовать реакт-контекст https://uk.reactjs.org/docs/context.html
3. Использовать redux для хранения стейта https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react/